# To redirect to partial popup view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, partial-views, popupwindow

Hi i'm using mvc3 in my application!!!!
I'm opening a popup window on click of a link to attach file

on the popup there are 2 buttons
1st button check for some validation like size and also save file on specified path

on the second button i need to save the file name to the database

Till now i can open the popup window like this

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Attach File", "attachFile", new { id = item.ID, size=itemFileSize }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup" })
```

and calling function like this from same view

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$("#result").dialog({ autoOpen: false,

    title: 'title',

    width: 800,

    height: 275,

    modal: true
});

function openPopup() {

    $("#result").dialog("open");

} </script>
```

this is running fine until i press the attach button on this popup and try to return the result to the popup

now this time when i call popup like

```
  return PartialView("attachFile",cwork);
```

the popup window does not open
instead it open as a normal form on window

Here is my code on attachFile view

```
 <form action="/Coursework/attachFile/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file1"/>
               </td>
               <td> <input type="submit" name="Attach" id="Attach" value="@Resources.prtf_Attach" />
               </td>
 </form>
  ....Below this is a submit button
```

please tell me how can i open the view in same popup window and not as normal page

Answer (score 1):

You should call popup open function on OnBegin in AjaxOptions Instead of OnSuccess. You should close popup when OnSuccess event fires

Comment: hey thanx for replying....but if i change to button then my function is not getting called

Comment: well for first time the popup is called from "index" view
i.e. from index view it will call partial view "attachFile"
But nexxt time i want to directly open "attachFile" view...
so in this case if i wrote OnBegin....it wont work for me

Comment: Try Ajax.BeginForm in attachFile view instead of normal form tag and place UpdateTargetId to "result".

Comment: But using this i'm not able to get the value of uploaded file